# Why is $\lim_{x \to \infty}(\int_0^n k^{1-x}\,\,di)^{1/(1-x)} = k$ when $k,n>0$ is constant real?

Tags: calculus, limits

Why is $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\int_0^n k^{1-x}\,\,di\right)^{1/(1-x)} = k$$
?

$k,n>0$ is constant real.

Comment: By $di$ I'm assuming you mean $dk$?

Comment: @ryagami Unlikely, as $k$ is a constant real.

Comment: I do mean $di$ even though no $i$ appears on the integral except $di$.

Answer (score 2):

$$Q = \int_0^n k^{1-x}\ di = \left[ik^{1-x}\right]_0^n = nk^{1-x}$$

$$$$
$$\text{Now, consider the following:}$$
$$$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} Q^{\large\frac{1}{1-x}} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\exp \left(\dfrac{\ln\left(nk^{1-x}\right)}{1-x}\right) = \lim_{x\to\infty}\exp\bigg(\dfrac{\ln(n)}{1-x}\bigg) \cdot \exp\bigg(\ln(k) \bigg)  = k$$

$$$$

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left[\int_0^n k^{1-x}\ di\right]^{\frac{1}{1-x}}= \lim_{x \to \infty}\left[ k^{1-x}\int_0^n di\right]^{\frac{1}{1-x}} $$
$$ = \lim_{x \to \infty}\left[ k^{1-x}(n-0)\right]^{\frac{1}{1-x}}= \lim_{x \to \infty}\left[ nk^{1-x}\right]^{\frac{1}{1-x}} $$
$$ = \lim_{x \to \infty}e^{\ln\left(nk^{1-x}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-x}}}= \lim_{x \to \infty}e^{\frac{\ln\left(nk^{1-x}\right)}{1-x}} $$
$$ = \lim_{x \to \infty}e^{\frac{\ln(n)+\ln\left(k^{1-x}\right)}{1-x}} = e^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(n)+(1-x)\ln(k)}{1-x}} $$
$$ = e^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left[\frac{\ln(n)}{1-x}+\ln(k)\right]}= e^{0+\ln(k)} =k$$

Answer (score 0):

You only need to compute the integral and use the laws of exponents. Note that
$$
\int _0^n k^{1-x}di= nk^{1-x}
$$
And use the fact that $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty }\frac{1}{1-x}=0$.

Comment: In that case the limit is equal to 1.

Comment: @Anuar I've corrected my answer. The exponent $k$ equals 1, so the answer is $k$